# Inserting elements into Binary Min Heaps

Tags: binary-tree

If I am inserting items: 10,12,14,1,6 into a binary min heap one item after another how would the results look like, my problem is with the following

when i start i have:

```
10
```

then

```
   10
  /
 12
```

then

```
   10
  /  \
 12  14
```

then

```
   1
  / \
 10 14
 /
12
```

but this is not right, so what is the right way to do that?

Note: this is a homework question, i am trying to understand the concept, if you don't feel comfortable solving the question (it is not the full question anyway) please provide an example with similar issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to add the new element as a child (or leaf exactly) to the heap (not as root), that means you put it in the first "right" free spot (or in your heap-array, just at the end).

Then you have to re-establish the heap conditions, this is called "heapify". This happens in two phases:

1. Repeatedly exchange the new element (general: the element that violates the heap conditions) with its parent node as long as it is smaller than the parent and it is not the root.
2. Repeatedly exchange the new element with the child with the smallest value, until the new element becomes a leave or both child nodes are bigger than the element itself.

That means

```
   10
  /  \
12    14
```

+ 1 leads to

```
    10
   /  \
 12    14
 /
1
```

And that violates the heap conditions, so you have to heapify

```
    10
   /  \
  1   14
 /
12
```

But this is still not right, so you have to heapify again

```
     1
   /  \
 10   14
 /
12
```

And there you are... everything OK now :-)

Comment: but 14 is more than 12, how is that ordered?

Comment: That doesn't violate the heap conditions... have a look at http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Min-heap.png 36 is greater than 19, 7 is greater than 2 and so on

Comment: Or to clarify: your solution is correct! I just explained how to get there algorithmic...

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old thread, but I believe the second step is not necessary, you just need to heapify up, no need to heapify back down.

Answer (score 2):

```
step1:     10
step2:     10
          /
         12
step3:     10
          /  \
         12   14
step4:     1
          /  \
         10  12
        /
       14
step5:     1
          / \
         6  10
        / \
       12  14
```